# How to solve your any component is not a known element in ngrx angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, components, ngrx, ngrx-store

1. Tried standalone strategy and also @ngModules but maybe i'm missing
   something in app.component.html or or in app.comopnent.ts.
2. Everything on my side is perfectly fine according to VScode and
   Angular support extension.
3. The issue seems to be related to the Angular compiler not recognizing
   the ReadDeleteComponent when it's declared in the AppModule.

   I don't know i'm really confused. Experts, help me!

```
Building...✘ [ERROR] NG8001: 'app-read-delete' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-read-delete' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-read-delete' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. [plugin angular-compiler]

    src/app/app.component.html:3:4:
      3 │     <app-read-delete></app-read-delete>
        ╵     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.

    src/app/app.component.ts:5:15:
      5 │   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
        ╵                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Application bundle generation failed. [2.311 seconds]
Watch mode enabled. Watching for file changes...
```

Here's my src/app/app.component.html

```
<app-read-delete></app-read-delete>
-----------------
```

Here's my src/app/app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'ngrx-store-hello-world';
}
```

here's my src/app/app.module.ts

```
// app.module.ts
import { StoreModule } from "@ngrx/store";
import { heroReducer } from "./heroes/reducers/hero-reducer";
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { ReadDeleteModule } from "./heroes/components/read-delete/read-delete.module";
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ReadDeleteModule, // Import the module only once
    StoreModule.forRoot(
      { heroes: heroReducer }
    )
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

here's is my src/app/heroes/components/read.delete.component.ts

```
// src/app/heroes/components/read-delete.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-read-delete',
  templateUrl: './read-delete.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./read-delete.component.scss'],
})

export class ReadDeleteComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

At last here's is read-delete-module.ts which is used to export read-deleteComponent.

```
// src/app/shared/read-delete.module.ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ReadDeleteComponent } from './read-delete.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ReadDeleteComponent],
  exports: [ReadDeleteComponent]
})
export class ReadDeleteModule { }
```

I've also tried standalone components still same error arises.

```
Angular CLI: 17.0.5
Node: 20.9.0
Package Manager: npm 10.1.0
OS: darwin x64
```

Comment: why did you go with the approach of having `app.module` but the `app.component` is standalone? You have multiple options, you could make the `app.component` not standalone, and make the `read.delete.component` standalone, then import the `read.delete.component` into `app.module`  imports array